# Table alignment in HTML

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a table with two columns, with a poem on the left and a translation on the right. The poem is long so it will be necessary to scroll down the page to read all of it. But I do not want the title of the poem and some links at the top of each column to scroll. The text of the poem should disappear below the title as one scrolls, with the title and the links in a fixed position. After various attempts I was able to almost get it done using two different tables: a table at the top containing the fixed title and links, and with the style option position:fixed, and another table just below with the text of the poem. I works just fine except for one thing: since I am using the same code for many different such poems, and the titles have varying length, I cannot get the title in the top table to be correctly aligned with the text in the bottom table. I can manually adjust the position of the title using left:90px (for example) for a specific page, but the same will not work with another page where the title of the poem is longer.  I am copying below the code I am using. This is a template used for over 200 different files. I have a script that substitutes the strings in all caps (like THE_TITLE, TRANSLATED_TEXT, etc.) with the appropriate content. As I mentioned, the problem is that if I adjust the parameters for the table at the top (that has position:fixed) for one particular content, it will not work for another content, because of the different length of the titles of the poems. My question is: is there a way to do what I want with two tables the way I am trying, or should I do it in a completely different way, and if so how?

```html
<table align="center" width=1200px style="position:fixed;top:270px;left:90px;">
<tr align="center"  >
<td style="text-align:center; z-index:20;"> <a href="FILENAME.php" style="text-decoration: 
none; color: #CC0000;">Seulement fran&ccedil;ais </a> </td> 
<td style="text-align:center; z-index:20;"> <a href="FILENAME_en.php" style="text- 
decoration: none; color: #04860a;">French and English </a> </td> </tr>
<tr align="center" style="z-index:20;" >
<th  align="center" style="z-index:20;"><font size=4> THE_TITLE </font> <br><br></th> 
<th  align="center" style="z-index:20;"> <font size=4>TRANSLATED_TITLE</font> <br><br></th>
</tr>
</table>
<table align="center" width=1200px >
<tr align="center">
<td  align="center" valign="top"> 
ORIGINAL_TEXT
</td>
<td  align="center" valign="top">
TRANSLATED_TEXT
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tried reading your question a few times... didn't understand...

Comment: I think what he tries to achieve is a fixed header like the last example on this page https://medium.com/@vembarrajan/html-css-tricks-scroll-able-table-body-tbody-d23182ae0fbc

Comment: Yes the example by @JavaMan is just what I would like, but with the complication that the width of the headers varies because the same code is used for many different pages.

Comment: @JavaMan I was able to use the example you pointed to without problems and it works great. The issue I was worried about was in fact a non-issue...Thanks!